# About actitivity lifecycle methods

Tags: android

I am working on an Android app

In MainActivity I am getting data from a webservice inside a method called `getData()`. Depending on the received data, I am calling another activity.

```
if (cel_verificado.equals("0")) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CEL NUMBER NOT VERIFIED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VerificarCelActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CEL NUMBER VERIFIED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

On the second activity, SignInActivity, I change the needed data, and then I go back to MainActivity again:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SignIn.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Back to MainActivity, I need to launch again the method `getData()`.

I am trying to do it inside `onRestart()` method, but it is not launched. I have also tried inside `onResume()`, but not launched.

```
@Override
public void onRestart(){
    super.onRestart();
    Log.d("SDOCKS", "ESTOY EN  : " +"on restart");
    getData();
}
```

I have been searching the activities lifecycle, and I thought both methods are launched when user returns to activity.

How could I force MainActivity to launch method `getData()` every time the user returns to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
On the second activity
Just call "finish()" instead of:
 Intent intent = new Intent(SignIn.this,MainActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);


And in MainActivity.class
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("SDOCKS", "ESTOY EN  : " +"on restart");
    getData();
}
```

Comment: @mvasco Hope this help out.. If you find any difficulty please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the following code is not running is because you are launching a new instance of MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SignIn.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Based on the activity lifecycle chart:

[image]

your app is calling `onCreate()`, not `onRestart()`, so your `getData()` call will never be executed. A couple things you have to do for this:

First, in SignInActivity, call `finish()` instead of calling

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SignIn.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Second, call `getData()` in `onStart()` or `onResume()`

Comment: but the call to getData() is already in onCreate at MainActivity

Comment: @mvasco from what you've mentioned it is in `onRestart()` only, not `onCreate()`

Comment: Sorry, but in my question you can see that getData() is called from MainActivity first. I didn't say it was at onRestart() only.

Comment: Please add that to your question for others, also have you tried just putting getData() in onResume()? That's kind of the "catch all" so I'd recommend you give that a shot first and take it out of both onCreate and onRestart

Answer (score 0):

Just destroy the next activity and your `MainActivity` will be resumed and call your `getData()` method always in `onResume()` it will be called no matter what. We destroy an Activity using the method:

```
finish();
```

Do **NOT** use `startActivity(intent);` to go back to the Main Activity it will be created as a new instance of it.

Comment: Also @mvasco when you are doing a toast inside any method in your activity just pass `this` instead `getApplicationContext()`. The huge context of the application may sometimes not work! but if is in the inner class be specific and say the whole activity `MainActivity.this` you have not asked this but just for your code performance I feel like saying it!

Comment: I thought the data  from getData came from the next activity. I have updated my answer! Good I have seen you update your code too! @mvasco